# Проблема присвоения значения элементам массива

Tags: массивы, матрицы, javascript

Господа!

Имею следующий код:

```
Array.prototype.fill = function(howMany, value){
    while(howMany--) this.push(value);
    return this;
}

var matrixSize = 4;
var matrix = [].fill(matrixSize,[].fill(matrixSize,0));

matrix[0][3]=1;
console.log(matrix);
```

По идее после присвоения

> matrix[0][3]=1;

должен получить

> 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0
> 1 0 0 0

а получаю

> 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0
> 1 1 1 1

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, решил следующим образом:

```
Array.prototype.fill = function(howMany, value){
   while(howMany--) {
      if(value instanceof Array)
          this.push(value.slice());
      else
          this.push(value);
   }
            return this;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var matrix = [].fill(matrixSize, [].fill(matrixSize,0));
```

Вы передаете массив по ссылке, а не по значению. Интерпретатор один раз вычисляет `[].fill(matrixSize,0)` и потом четыре раза вставляет ссылку на созданный объект.